# Starting IntentService periodically with AlarmManager - Losing Data at certain point

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcast, android-intentservice

In my app, I want to send sensor data every ten seconds via POST to a webserver.
I am doing this with an activity who starts/stopps a `AlarmMananger` who is calling an IntentService.

Problem is: the target URL is generated in the Activity and doesn't arrive at the IntentService.

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        String targetURL = "www.google.de";
        alarmIntent.putExtra("targetURL", targetURL);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);

    }

    ...
}
```

Broadcast-Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String targetURL = intent.getStringExtra("targetURL");
        Intent newintent = new Intent(context, SendPostRequest_Service.class);
        newintent.putExtra("targetURL", targetURL);
        context.startService(newintent);
    }
}
```

Intent Service:

```
public class SendPostRequest_Service extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener{
    ...
    public SendPostRequest_Service() {
        super(SendPostRequest_Service.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String targetURL = intent.getStringExtra("targetURL");
        // Problem: targetURL = null
        //read sensors, send POST-Request via okhttp <- working
    }
    ...
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked in the BroadcastReceiver, to see if Extra is non-null there?  I wonder if the call to PendingIntent.getBroadcast copies the Intent over.  If so, it will have a copy that does not contain the Extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code into a test project. Only way I was able to get it working was to change the order of when the extra is added to the intent. Update MyActivty with the below. It would appear to G. Blake Meike point that there's a copy of the intent being done.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    String targetURL = "www.google.de";
    alarmIntent.putExtra("targetURL", targetURL);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: Tried the same seconds after G. Blake Meike's comment. It works, thanks!

Comment: Wouldnt that cause a new repeating alaram to be created each time the service runs? instead of just the one we want?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take a wake lock in your `BroadcastReceiver` and release it in your `Service`. Otherwise, the system may return to a sleep state before your `Service` gets a chance to run. The `WakefulReceiver` is particularly useful for this. If you'd like some more details, this article will help: http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/

Comment: Larry is right in most circumstances but in this case, it appears that the AlarmService is only running when the Activity is in the foreground.  In that case, no wakelock is needed.  Further, it would be much more effective to use a delayed task, on the IntentService Looper, to post every 10 secs.  None of this, alas, addresses the actual problem!

Comment: You are right @G.BlakeMeike, the AlarmService has to run only when the activity is in the foreground. Could the null-reference be some kind of context problem?

Comment: It's an honor, @LarrySchiefer!  Your articles are awesome.